# RegEx: Extract all complete words before N characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am looking for a short way to capture the first part of a sentence (in complete words) until the 30th character.

Example: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" (55 chars) --> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," (28 chars)

I will use this in Google Sheet, so the solution can be a combination of RegEx and formulas, but it needs to be super concise because it will be applied over a big range of data.

Comment: If you're using javascript, you can try `^.*\b(?<=^.{0,30})`, check [here](https://regex101.com/r/OIQSqh/1) to see the result.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your regex. Unfortunately, it will not work with `REGEXEXTRACT()` from Google Sheet, so I am still stuck with a super long formula for now (namely `=if(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(C$3,"^(?:\S+\s+\n?){1,"&counta(SPLIT(LEFT(C$3,30)," ",true, true))&"}"))<=30,REGEXEXTRACT(C$3,"^(?:\S+\s+\n?){1,"&counta(SPLIT(LEFT(C$3,30)," ",true, true))&"}"),REGEXEXTRACT(C$3,"^(?:\S+\s+\n?){1,"&counta(SPLIT(LEFT(C$3,30)," ",true, true))-1&"}"))`)

Comment: My previous solution didn't take into account all the use cases, so I updated my answer. I hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a very concise formula, you could use an Apps Script [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

First, open a bound script by selecting `Tools > Script editor`, and copy the following function to the script (check inline comments):

```js
function FIRST_WORDS(input, number) {
  if (input.length <= number) return input;
  input = input.substring(0, number + 1);
  const lastSpace = input.lastIndexOf(" ");
  if (lastSpace === -1) return "";
  return input.slice(0, lastSpace);
}
```

Once it is defined, you can use this function the same you would any sheets built-in function. You just need to specify the source range and the number of characters (in this case, 30):

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)